# Check if all elements in numpy array match a number

Tags: python, numpy

In my python testing script, I want to assert if all elements of numpy array are either very close to 1.0 or equal to 0.0. The array looks like this:

```
[[0.9999999991268851 1.0000000223517418 0.999999986961484 ...,
  0.9999999841675162 1.0000000074505806 0.9999999841675162]
 [0.9999999991268851 1.0000000223517418 0.999999986961484 ...,
  0.9999999841675162 1.0000000074505806 0.9999999841675162]
 [0.9999999991268851 1.0000000223517418 0.999999986961484 ...,
  0.9999999841675162 1.0000000074505806 0.9999999841675162]
 ..., 
 [1.0000000198488124 1.0000000074505806 1.000000002568413 ...,
  0.9999999888241291 0.9999999925494194 0.0]
 [1.000000011001248 0.9999999850988388 0.9999999869323801 ...,
  1.0000000186264515 0.9999999925494194 0.0]
 [1.000000011001248 0.9999999850988388 0.9999999869323801 ...,
  1.0000000186264515 0.9999999925494194 0.0]]
```

I thought of using numpy.allclose or numpy.array_equal, but neither makes sense here. ideally, the function should be able to be used in a testing scenario

Comment: What is _"very close to"_?

Comment: I think you are looking at something like numpy's `assert_almost_equal`. See the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_almost_equal.html) for examples.

Comment: Why doesn't `allclose` make sense? (It broadcasts!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the 0 elements and mask them out using boolean indexing.  Once that's done, `np.allclose` is exactly what you want:

```
zeros = arr == 0.0
without_zeros = arr[~zeros]
np.allclose(without_zeros, 1, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I can think of would just be to iterate over every element of the array and test if it is either close to one or equal to zero:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0.9999999991268851, 1.0000000223517418, 0.999999986961484],
                [1.0000000186264515, 0.9999999925494194, 0.0]])

def is_one_or_zero(arr):
  for elem in np.nditer(arr):
    if not (elem == 0 or np.isclose(1.0, elem)):
      return False
  return True

print is_one_or_zero(arr) # Should be True
arr[0, 0] = 1.01
print is_one_or_zero(arr) # Should be False
```

Comment: I'd iterate over `arr.flat` instead of assuming it's a 2D array.

Comment: @mgilson I changed it to use `np.nditer`. Is there any advantage to `arr.flat` versus `np.nditer`?

Comment: I dunno :-).  Probably not a huge difference between the two -- though it's been a while since I've worked with numpy heavily, so I could be wrong here...

Comment: `arr.flat` is a fairly simple iterator that always iterates in c-contiguous order. `nditer` is capable of much more complex operations, see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html). On a side note, python loops for numpy arrays is usually not a good idea due to the severe python performance penalty.